# Android Audio Device Firebase Test Lab Integration

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

I am currently looking to run instrumentation tests in Firebase Test Lab for an audio routing Android library that I am working on. Is there any support for integrating physical or virtual audio devices with any of the available Android test devices in Firebase Test Lab? We would need at least one wired headset and one bluetooth headset. If so, can these devices be programmatically connected/disconnected from an Instrumentation test?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Firebase Test Lab does not have support for this sort of test integration. Here's the response from the Firebase Test Lab support team.

`"Unfortunately this doesn't sound like a use case that Test Lab will be able to support. There's certainly no way to programmatically connect a physical headset to a specific physical device sitting in a datacenter."`